How can I display each ID only once based on their latest date by selected period?
I have a PBI challenge. The user wants to see each ID in Dynamic Date Chart but for their latest date BASED on the date filter.
For example, my table with columns:



ID
Date/hour




003
15-03-2024 14:00


003
15-03-2024 15:00


003
19-03-2024 15:00


009
15-03-2024 15:00


009
18-03-2024 15:00



I have a Date chart where i show the unique count of ID.
If my Date Slicer (from dim_Calendar) is selected from 1-03-2024 to 31-03-2024 i want to see only 2 IDS - ID 009 in 18-03-2024 and ID 003 in 19-03-2024;
If my Date Slicer is selected from 1-03-2024 to 18-03-2024 i want to see only 2 IDS - ID 009 in 18-03-2024 and ID 003 in 15-03-2024;
and again If my Date Slicer is selected from 1-03-2024 to 17-03-2024 i want to see only 2 IDS - ID 009 in 15-03-2024 and ID 003 in 15-03-2024;
So this way I only see the one with the LATEST date within my slicer selection;
I have tried a lot of measures but somehow, they still do not work.
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'MyTable',
            'MyTable'[Date/hour] = 
                CALCULATE(
                    MAX('MyTable'[Date/hour]),
                    ALLEXCEPT(
                        'MyTable' ,
                        'MyTable'[ID]
                    )
                )
        )
    )
)


UPDATE:
I have added a new Rank column



ID
Date/hour
Rank




003
15-03-2024 14:00
3


003
15-03-2024 15:00
2


003
19-03-2024 15:00
1


009
15-03-2024 15:00
2


009
18-03-2024 15:00
1



So the lowest value in the Rank column is the latest row for each ID.
I have written this measure:


1 test =  VAR _min_rank = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         MIN( 'MyTable'[Rank] ) ,
>         ALLSELECTED( d_Calendar[Date] )
>     ) VAR _table =
>     FILTER(
>         ADDCOLUMNS(
>             SUMMARIZE(
>                 'MyTable' , 
>                 'MyTable'[ID] ,
>                 'MyTable'[Rank]
>             ) ,
>             "#latest_date" ,
>             CALCULATE(
>                 MIN( 'MyTable'[Rank] ) ,
>                 ALLSELECTED( d_Calendar[Date] ) 
>             )
>         ) ,
>         'MyTable'[Rank] = [#latest_date]
>     ) VAR RESULT = 
>     COUNTROWS( _table ) 
> 
> RETURN RESULT

This almost gives me the expected result, but when I have only 1 ID selected whenever i move my date slicer it gives me the result but when there are multiple ID's selected It takes the lowest Rank and shows only the ones that share same lowest rank. :(
Why does

        CALCULATE(
            MIN( 'MyTable'[Rank] ) ,
            ALLSELECTED( d_Calendar[Date] ) 
        )


this part does not work as it is expected to work? :(


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I hope I understood your requirement correctly. This can be achieved by following measure. Use case of the measure can vary.
Rank count =
VAR maxselectedval =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Date/hour] )
VAR minselectedval =
    MIN ( 'Table'[Date/hour] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ),
        'Table'[Date/hour] >= minselectedval
            && 'Table'[Date/hour] <= maxselectedval
    ) 

If the dates are between below, it will give 2

If the dates are between below, it will give 1

UPDATE
I have re-written the measure to support the latest date
Latest ID = 
VAR max_date =
    max ( 'Table'[Date/hour] )
VAR tmp =
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date/hour] >= max_date )
VAR ctn = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID])
RETURN
    IF ( ctn = 0, 0, ctn )

If you want the sample file, get it from this link

Hello!
Sorry but no :(
Each ID should be counted only once based on they latest date/hour which is filtered within a slicer.
If my slicer is for the whole period ID 003 is in 19-03 and ID 009 in 18-03.
If i use a slicer for 1-march to 15-march ID 003 is in 15-03 and ID 009 is in 15-03. (so in 15-03 i will have 2 of a count).

Check the update above

you need to have a date table and do not create relationship between the date table and your fact table.
The slicer is from your data table.
Then create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _min =
    MIN ( 'date'[Date] )
VAR _max =
    MAX ( 'date'[Date] ) + 1
VAR _max2 =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[ID] = MAX ( 'Table'[ID] )
                && 'Table'[Date/hour] >= _min
                && 'Table'[Date/hour] < _max
        ),
        'Table'[Date/hour]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _max2 = MAX ( 'Table'[Date/hour] ), 1, 0 )

Then add this measure to table visual and set to 1



